# Android Device not detecting in ecclips

Tags: java, emulation

I have installed all required drivers of mobile. My device is able to detect in' adb device'. but while running application, my mobile device is not coming..

In "device" it is able to locate.

I have gone through: "Run-> Run Configuration-> target" but there is no any active device.

Comment: Restart your device, it will be working  then.

Comment: I have done it lots of time...

Comment: this issue get solved... I have directly gone ahead and ran the application, while there is no any active device available. And it worked!
I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue solved...
I changed SDK folder with another latest version of SDK externally.
Restarted Computer. Configured device.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I experienced that too. The reason can be anything... Try updating you adb / usb drivers. Maybe you gonna need a vendor-specific usb-driver. 
Last time when I had problems with detecting my Sony Xperia S, I solved them by turning USB Modem in Preferences on.

Comment: I ca view my mobile device in "adb devices list"

Comment: try selecting "always prompt to pick device"

Comment: this issue get solved... I have directly gone ahead and ran the application, while there is no any active device available. And it worked!
I appreciate your suggestions.